# Flutter Row() - Align 3 widgets evenly in any amount of Columns

Tags: flutter, flutter-streambuilder

I need to show whole my options(Cyties) since Firebase DB in my app so I would like create somethig similar to the screenshot I posted and not quite sure how to. The only way I know to do it is with ListTile and is not the idea.[app Colombia from Play Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p8oS.jpg)

I just tried with a ListTile. And Im sure I need an StreamBuilder since the begining.

[This is what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEHoo.png)

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: Please add code snippet for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use GridView rather then Listview like below

```
GridView.builder(  
              itemCount: item.length,  
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(  
                  crossAxisCount: 3,  
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0, //Adjust spacing as per yours 
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0  
              ),  
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){  
                return //Your Widget in which you want to display for //example Container();  
              },  
            )),
```